# Reducing spice in sauce

Tags: sauce, spicy-hot

How do you make already prepared sauce less spicy? I must have used too many hot chili peppers or cooked them too long. Is there something to off set it from being so hot? The sauce is for General Tso's Chicken

Answer (score 0):

There is no robust way to do this in the general case, other than to create  second batch with no additional hot peppers (or a reduced quantity), and combine them.  Of course, then you will have twice as much product.

In some cases, adding a masking agent like sour cream or cheese, which tame the effect of the spiciness may help, but those methods would be very odd with a Chinese dish.

Depending on the degree to which you have over-spiced your sauce, simply using it more sparingly may help.   Traditionally, Chinese food is not swimming in sauce in any case.